# NoSQL advantages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nosql, redis

Why is NoSQL said to be structurally faster than some SQL db? Suppose I add some index on a column of some SQL table. Can someone provide some kind of faster queries?

I was reading about redis.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def follow!(user)
    $redis.multi do
      $redis.sadd(self.redis_key(:following), user.id)
      $redis.sadd(user.redis_key(:followers), self.id)
    end
  end
....
```

Despite the RAM storage of redis, how can this code be structurally faster than setting some followship tables? Core symbol tables implementation are built upon arrays, which can be thought of as SQL table ids.

As for the RAM redis memory storage, how can it persist?

Comment: There is no such thing as NoSQL. There is just a whole bunch of new database technologies which don't have much to do with each other. While some of them can do some things faster than SQL databases, there are also some other things some of them do much slower or can not do at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why some* NoSQL databases are faster than some* SQL databases at some* operations is, because some* of them work much simpler. Over the years, some* relational database management systems accumulated a lot of feature-creep. Most* relational databases are much more than just tables of data. They have auto-optimizing indexes, transactions,  foreign key relations, constraints, triggers, stored procedures, enforced consistency, intelligent views, exotic data-types, esoteric query commands and much more.

For comparison: Redis is currently about 20.000 lines of code. MySQL, on the other hand, is over 1.5 million LoC by now! Don't get me wrong, all* these features have their reason for existing. But none of them are free. They all require trade-offs which make other* operations slower.

Most* NoSQL databases, on the other hand, are newer developments which have thrown all that complexity over board and concentrate only on what matters most: fast retrieval of information by index. This simplicity make some* NoSQL databases appear a lot faster and efficient at first. But keep in mind that these come at a price: When you actually need these features provided by many* relational databases, you usually have to replicate them through very convoluted queries or by making multiple queries and doing the rest on the application level. That can make some* NoSQL databases even slower for some* use-cases.

Bottom-line: NoSQL databases are just more tools for your toolbox. Maybe you have some problems they solve better than your old tools. But other problems might be more fitting for your old tools.

Regarding the coexistence of RAM storage and persistence in one database: Those* databases usually perform write-operations in RAM, report success (or failure) and persist these changes later. Read-operations are first served from RAM and only when the information isn't found there they look on the hard-drive. This improves responsiveness of writes and lookup speed for recently accessed data, but has the risk of loss of recent data in case of a sudden crash.

*) not all, there are exceptions

Comment: Most famous Nosql databases e.g. mongodb, nosdb (I have used them both) have Journal. The user operations get inserted into the journal immediately so in can of db crash the operation gets re-applied. Using the Journal almost nullifies the data loss. About queries, the distributed nature of NoSql makes the query processing faster because firstly the query results are computed on small amount of data available at each node and then result gets combined at Query Router. Obviously every node has smaller amount of data therefore you can compute the result faster. Think in terms of Time Complexity.